# Why does the Internal style sheet works and External style sheet don't?

Tags: css

I am helping to create a website, we are two people working on this project. The other person is responsible for the visual part (CSS, html and javascript), I'm responsible for the internal functioning of the website (php, javascript and database, ...).

I created a code for the site pop up error messages.

I used some css to create the pop up mensage and i't work when I use the internal style sheet.

The problem it's when I use external style sheet, the pop up effect it's not working.

I did some research and find that this could be caused by encoding the css.

So to solve this problem I'm doing this:

In my  mystyle.css:

```
 @charset "utf-8";
```

In my head.php:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

But this did not solve my problem.

I did some more research and there is the possibility of being caused by fetching the external css in the wrong place.

I think it's not caused by this because the other person's css are working. I'm saving my css in the same folder as the other person is saving hers. I call the css files the same as the other person.

My head.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/css/bootstrap.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base_url;?>/css/mystyle.css">
```

What could be causing this, or am I doing something wrong?

My full code for external style sheet.

mystyle.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

        .modal-error-box {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding: 200px 0px 100px 0px;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }


        /* The Close Button */
        .close{
            color: black;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .modal-error-box-header{
            margin: auto;
            width: 35%;
            height: 5%;
            border: 3px solid black;
            background-color: Red;
            color: Black;
        }

        .modal-error-box-body 
        {
            margin: auto;
            width: 35%;
            height: 20%;
            border: 3px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: white;
            color: Black;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
```

html:

```
<div id="erro-gravar-operacoes" class = "modal-error-box">
        <div id ="error-gravar-header1" class = "modal-error-box-header">
            Mensagem de ERRO:
            <span id="close-erro1" class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div id = "erro-gravar-body1" class="modal-error-box-body">
        </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function validatesubmitform(id_var)
{

    //validate form.

    if(validate == false){

                    var div_error = document.createElement("p");
                    div_error.setAttribute('id', "id_element_erro" );
                    if(text_erro!="")
                    {
                        var element_erro = document.createElement("p"); 
                        element_erro.setAttribute('id', "id_element_erro1" );
                        var texto_erro = document.createTextNode(text_erro);
                        element_erro.appendChild(texto_erro);
                        div_error.appendChild(element_erro);

                    }
                    if(text_erro1!="")
                    {
                        var element_erro1 = document.createElement("p");
                        element_erro1.setAttribute('id', "id_element_erro2" );
                        var texto_erro1 = document.createTextNode(text_erro1);
                        element_erro1.appendChild(texto_erro1);
                        div_error.appendChild(element_erro1);
                    }
                    var div_display = document.getElementById("erro-altera-body2");
                    div_display.appendChild(div_error);
                    document.getElementById("erro-altera-operacoes").style.display='block';    
        }
        return validate;

}
```

Help with this problem is really necessary, and greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for future contributions to solving this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the accessrights of the files?

Comment: Could you present your CSS file please?

Comment: Check the console log for any errors, that might be helpful.
Also if you're working on linux you might have no permission to open those files in the browser.
Inspect the head in the browser and check the links to make sure they really go in the right place, basically open the direct link that's presented in the head to see if the files load.

Comment: Another suggestion (you make people guess here by not including a [mcve] :-)): when your CSS is not valid, browsers may not apply all/any styles. You can check your stylesheet using the [W3C validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). There's also a [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I agree with the above comments. also, browser cache may need to be cleared. first step of action must be deciding if this is a server-side or client-side problem. You need to get the request urls for those files and make seperate requests to those links (ex: seperate tabs in a browser).  And do a markup check for response payloads. if the incoming payload is correct, then there is something wrong with how you're handling these payloads inside your html.

Comment: You also may check the error logs of your server for issues

Comment: I have no error in my error console. The only thing is that the error message does not pop up when I use the external style sheet.

Comment: @Arthur it's the problem of the permission. when I put the direct link in my head.php the pop up appeared. Thanks for the help, if you put your comment as an answer I will accept it to give the question as completed.

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by giving yourself write permission in the css folder

Ubuntu: sudo chown -R username /.../.../.../.../css

If everything seems to be fine and some files don't load, check the file permissions.

Comment: using permissions 777 is NOT the greatest solution since you're giving access to your files to everyone right now.

Comment: @Deathstorm , I didn't say it was the greatest solution and I did specify that everybody will have access to them. The best option would be to chown them. I was in a rush and I didn't get to add that bit.

Comment: I'm not using the chmod -R 777 /path/to/files. I give my self permission to the folder css and created a new css file this works fine for me. I tested using another user and it's working. I'll accept your answer, but I do not really recommend it, because of security issues.

Comment: I removed the chmod part.